# SQLAlchemy TypeError when creating model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm new to flask and SQLAlchemy and this is the code I'm trying to run:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app =Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/example'
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

class  Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__='persons'
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(), nulllable=False)

db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'test'
```

But it keeps giving me this error:

```
* Environment: production
    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
    Use a production WSGI server instead. 
* Debug mode: off 
    C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:872:
        FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.
        Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
        warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 7,
    in <module>
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 986, in main
    cli.main()
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 567, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 848, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 279, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 313, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 373, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, None, raise_if_not_found=False)
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 214, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
File "D:\class\app.py", line 8, in <module>
    class  Person(db.Model):
File "D:\class\app.py", line 11, in Person
    name=db.Column(db.String(), nulllable=False)
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 1771, in __init__
    self._extra_kwargs(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 1813, in _extra_kwargs
    self._validate_dialect_kwargs(kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 424, in _validate_dialect_kwargs
    raise TypeError( TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'nulllable'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your traceback, the last line points at the problem - it didn't expect a keyword argument you're passing to the column initializer (spacing added to make it fit and make the error more obvious).

```
File "C:\Users\Dell-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 424, in _validate_dialect_kwargs
    raise TypeError(
      TypeError: Additional arguments should be named 
      <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'nulllable'
```

You misspelled the keyword argument `nullable` when creating the `name` column on your table as `nulllable` (extra `l`). Your model should look like this

```
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
```